# quotation marks trigger Intellisense in Pylance

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to manage the characters that trigger Intellisense in Visual Code?

Today, Visual Code started triggering Intellisense on single and double quotation marks in Python. This is presumably due to the recent Pylance integration:

[image]

This is maddening because when you're typing you can no longer hit the `Enter` key after a quotation mark in order to create a new line.

It's possible to disable Intellisense's character triggering by adding the following line in **settings.json**:

```
{
    // Controls if suggestions should automatically show up when typing trigger characters
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
}
```

However, this is not ideal, so I'm wondering whether this is a bug or a feature, and whether there's another way to solve this?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue with brackets - no, I don't want to get auto-complete in every single list, thank you!

I don't get this problem with strings, though, and I think it's because I have this snippet in my settings. This comes right from the VSCode docs on suggestions.

`"editor.quickSuggestions": { "strings": false}`